# Unabe to create samples using opencv_createsamples.exe

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

Im trying to train a haar cascade. For that as a test run, I'm taking 5 positive images (which have the image). I use a program called objectmarker.exe to mark the object in the image and store the coordinates as well as the height and width of the rectangle in a text file (positives.txt)

Now when I try to create a .vec file using the the text file from command line, the program executes, but i get the following:

positive(1).txt : parse errorDone. Created 0 samples

The .vec file does get generated but if i try to view it, it opens a window and crashes.

I use the following code

```
C:\Sahil\Major Project\Haartraining Stuff\Haartraining Stuff\STEPS\step 02>openc
v_createsamples.exe -info positives.txt -num5 -vec vec5.vec -w 20 -h 20
Info file name: positives.txt
Img file name: (NULL)
Vec file name: vec5.vec
BG  file name: (NULL)
Num: 1000
BG color: 0
BG threshold: 80
Invert: FALSE
Max intensity deviation: 40
Max x angle: 1.1
Max y angle: 1.1
Max z angle: 0.5
Show samples: FALSE
Width: 20
Height: 20
Create training samples from images collection...
positives.txt(1) : parse errorDone. Created 0 samples
```

my postives.txt is in the following format

```
C:/Sahil/Major Project/Haartraining Stuff/Haartraining Stuff/STEPS/step 02/rawdata/00007 001 (3).bmp_0000_0065_0107_0107_0199.bmp 1 1 2 106 193
C:/Sahil/Major Project/Haartraining Stuff/Haartraining Stuff/STEPS/step 02/rawdata/00007 001 (4).bmp_0000_0065_0107_0107_0199.bmp 1 1 2 108 195
C:/Sahil/Major Project/Haartraining Stuff/Haartraining Stuff/STEPS/step 02/rawdata/00007 001.bmp_0000_0065_0107_0107_0199.bmp 1 2 5 110 195
C:/Sahil/Major Project/Haartraining Stuff/Haartraining Stuff/STEPS/step 02/rawdata/img1.bmp 1 4 4 103 190
C:/Sahil/Major Project/Haartraining Stuff/Haartraining Stuff/STEPS/step 02/rawdata/img2.bmp 1 3 5 118 217
```

kindly suggest what i can do to correct this error. as i cannot proceed further

Comment: I have tried using both .png and .bmp image formats with 300x300 dimensions. however same problem in either case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is opencv_createsamples.exe distinguishing image file names? It might be written not to check white characters in paths/file names. Try without spaces either in the paths and file names.

Comment: im using the default file, opencv_createsamples.exe which i got with the opencv package. I will try renaming files without spaces

Comment: sometimes the simplest things are missed ;)